# Best way to reset entity manager

Tags: php, symfony

What's the best to reset an doctrine entity manager when I have a PdoException ?

In a foreach loop I need to save the maximum entities I got. If one entity failed, I want to send an email and keep running the foreach loop.

Example:

```
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function testMethod(array $entities)
{
    foreach ($entities as $entity)
    {
        try 
        {
            $entity = new MyEntity();
            $entity->setSomeData();
            $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        } catch (\Exception $e)
        {
          //SEND EMAIL
        }
    }
}
```

Some time, I got the message "EntityManager is closed.", throw by a PdoException.

What's the best way to reset my entity manager to keep going my loop ?

NB: This is a sample code. I don't send email or flush for each errors.

Comment: should there ever be errors? seems like this shouldn't be desired behaviour?

Comment: why aren't you flushing after the for each? why not wait until you know the final result and then send an email with what might have happened during the single flush? i don't get what you're actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have a LOT of constraints validations but sometime, one error may prevent the save. I can't stop the process just for 1 or 2 bad entities. I prefer fix manually.

Comment: I think this idea generally is bad design ... are you sure you want to have tons of mails if your database is down? Instead your failing part should throw an exception you catch in your code and keep going on the loop. Persist once at the end and send mail with all missing items afterwards.

Comment: I'll send just one email. This is just an example ;)

Comment: I don't persist at every iterations.

Comment: If you really want to anticipate this kind of error you can check if the entity manager is open before each data processing like this : `if(!$entityManager->isOpen()) { // throw an exception for example }` (Keep in mind that it is just a patch and not a real solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something you could do to improve performance: you just call outside your loop. So that memory will be flushed only at the end of all persists. `$this->entityManager->flush();`

But you can try to call `$this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();` If you need to keep saving things after an exception is thrown.

Comment: Ok, I got it. If you call flush only at the end of the foreach you won't be able to save all at once If an exception is thrown. But try to reset the manager, maybe it works.

Comment: How could you resetManger if you are in a Service with the Entity Manager injected? You wouldn't be able to call $this->getDoctrine()....

Comment: @Angel you have to inject ManagerRegistry in constructor and call $registry->resetManager()

Comment: @Angel Is It a problem to inject `doctrine` to service?